# PEAR->Mail.php recipients and To Header

Tags: php, pear

If I set the recipients do I also need to set the TO header?

I am setting the To header like this (From an EE template in an EE plugin):

```
$headers["To"]      = $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('send_to');
```

and then the recipient like this:

```
$recipients         = $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('send_to');
```

Then sending like this:

```
$mail_object        =& Mail::factory("smtp", $smtpinfo);
$mail_result        = $mail_object->send($recipients, $headers, $email_msg);
```

Do I really need to do both of them?

Comment: why have you used an ambersand before mail::factory ?

Comment: can i see ur full code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will reach the recipients. However if you leave the key 'To' in the header blank it will show "undisclosed-recipients" for the reader in their mail client.

Comment: But if I set ONLY the To header will it still be delivered?

Comment: No. You can leave the $headers["To"] out, but not the $recipients.

Comment: I went ahead and set both. Thanks.